# Remove UIView referenced from its child?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

If I have `UIView` that contains a Label

[image]

Is it possible to reference and remove the `TitleContainer` view?? referenced from the child that has an outlet connected to the controller

Note: I don't want to use tags

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let parent = self.lbl.superview!
parent.removeFromSuperview()
```